# Get all comments of author's posts

Tags: posts, comments, query, author

Hello I have multi author website. I want to display all comments of posts created by author in author page. Please help me. I found this code but fatal error

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'author' => AUTHOR_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 500, //Don't use -1 here
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
            $nested_args = array(
                'post_id' => get_the_ID()
            );
            $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
            $comments = $comments_query->query( $nested_args );
            if ( $comments ) {
                foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
                    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
                }
            }
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's two problem with the code you're trying to use. The first is `AUTHOR_ID`. Unless you have this defined somewhere else, then this is going to cause an undefined constant error. The second one is that there should be a closing PHP tag `?>` before `<?php endwhile; ?>`.

Another thing is, that doing `WP_Query` is a bit unnecessary as you can pass the user ID as a parameter to the [`WP_Comment_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Comment_Query/__construct/) directly.

For example on `author.php` template you could do this,

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Comment_Query( array(
    'user_id' => get_queried_object_id()
) );

foreach ($query->comments as $comment) {
    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

To get comments from the author's posts, use `post_author` parameter.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Comment_Query( array(
    'post_author' => get_queried_object_id()
) );

foreach ($query->comments as $comment) {
    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I am so sorry. in my question . I mean author's posts comments . these comments written by readers of post

Comment: @TeymurAbbasov, I'm sorry for the misunderstandment. To get the comments from posts where the user is the post author, simply swap the `user_id` parameter to `post_author`.

Comment: Thank very much